# split urls to directories and convert into json tree

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv file containing my website URLs into a json tree structure based on directories in URLs. the complexe thing is that the depth of an URL structure (NB of directories) can vary from an URL to another, so I must have a recursive function that handle all possibilities.

for the example, here is my list of URLs :

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/page1.html
https://example.com/cocktails/receipe/page1.html
https://example.com/cocktails/receipe/page2.html
https://example.com/cocktails/page3.html
https://example.com/article/magazine
https://example.com/article/mood/page1.html
```

what I want to get is a JSON tree like this :

```
{
"name": "/",
"children": [{
        "name": "page1.html"
    },
    {
        "name": "cocktails",
        "children": [{
                "name": "recipe",
                "children": [{
                        "name": "page1.html"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "page2.html"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "page3.html"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "article",
        "children": [{
                "name": "mood",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "page1.html"
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "magazine"
            }
        ]
    }

]
}
```

I started a code using Python but I'm blocked in the recursive way to handling the children

```
import json
import re, csv
from collections import OrderedDict


def run() :
    root = OrderedDict({
        "name": "/",
        "children": [],
    })
    rows = csv.DictReader(open("test.csv"))
    for row in rows :
        link = row['url']
        suffix = re.sub("https?://[^/]*","", link)
        parts = [x for x in re.split("[/\?]", suffix) if x != ""]

        if len(parts) ==0 :
            continue

        if len(parts) == 1:
            p = parts[0]
            if p not in root :
                root[p]["children"].append(create_row(p, row))
        else :
            page = parts[-1]
            parts = parts[:-1]

            """
            SOME CODE HERE
            """
    data = json.dumps(root, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
    open("readme.json", "w").write(data)

def create_row(key, row) :
    return {"name": key,
        "url": row['link'].strip()
        }

def key_exists(folders, key) :
    return [x for x in folders if x['name'] == key] > 0


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below program gives your expected output I hope its not too complicated for you.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
a=["/",
"/page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page1.html",
"/cocktails/receipe/page2.html",
"/cocktails/page3.html",
"/article/magazine",
"/article/mood/page1.html"]

def create (path,dictionaryarray):
    headarray = dictionaryarray
    for index,element in enumerate(path):
        exists = 0
        for head in headarray:
            if head['name'] == element:
                head.setdefault('children',[])
                headarray = head['children']
                exists =1
                break
        if not exists:
            if index == len(path) - 1: 
                headarray.append({'name':element})
            else:
                headarray.append({'name':element,'children':[]})
                headarray=headarray[-1]['children']
d = []        
for i in a:
    create([j for j in i.split('/') if j != ''] ,d)

data={'name':'/','children':d}
data=json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
# pprint(data)
print(data)
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "name": "/",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "page1.html"
        },
        {
            "name": "cocktails",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "receipe",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "page1.html"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "page2.html"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "page3.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "article",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "magazine"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mood",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "page1.html"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm trying a PHP implementation, but get a `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached` error. Ok I understand what the error means but can't get where I do the infinite loop... any chance you can have a look to my code here ? https://gist.github.com/karibot/5a313d13b421d4f3a43bf2c0577498e6

Comment: @DanyM I have changed the code to iterative fashion if that helps and Im sorry, I dont write PHP, I used to but not now.

Comment: thanks :) I'll give it a try with PHP. I'll post here my progress

Comment: I have trouble with populating `dictionaryarray` by reference with PHP...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion here. You can build the tree by traversing the paths & appending children as you go.

Pseudocode:

```
roots = []
For each row:
    parse the URL
    if part[0] not in root:
        create root node in roots
    for each part of the path in the url
        cur_node = find the corresponding root in roots
        if part is not in the children list of cur_node:
             create child entry in cur_node
             cur_node = the child entry you just created
```

Comment: Implemented this in Javascript. Works great. Thanks